# Point the reference name into another Path in VB.Net Windows Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

Good day!

I am actually new to VB.Net Winform development.

I have a case wherein I need to point the reference into another path of the correct dll file. This is essential because the current path the reference is pointing to has an outdated dll file.

[image]

I need to point it into another path,

I tried modifying the property, but the path is disabled, are there other correct way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 - delete the reference, then add a new reference and browse to the correct path. What I normally do.

Option 2 - Unload the project in Solution Explorer. Choose to Edit the project file. Locate the reference in the XML and update the hint path.

Yes, it would be much nicer if there was an edit experience directly for the path property.